# After compiling Postgresql 12 hstore extension was not found

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I have compiled PostgreSQL 12 with the following code.

```
curl --progress-bar https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v12.2/postgresql-12.2.tar.bz2 | tar xj -C /usr/local/src/

cd src/postgresql-12.2
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-pgport=5432 --with-python --with-openssl --with-libxml --with-libxslt --with-zlib --with-llvm
    make -j "$(nproc)"
    make install
    make all
    make install
cd ../..
ldconfig
```

After that I am trying to create `hstore` extension. but it is returning the following error

> ERROR:  could not open extension control file
>   "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/hstore.control": No such file
>   or directory

How can I get that extension work for my compilation.
N.B. I do not want to use `apt-get` or `yum`, I want to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Some extensions are distributed with the source code in `postgres/contrib` directory but are neither built nor installed by default: you need to go in `postgres/contrib/hstore` directory and to run the usual steps:

```
make
make install
```

And you can run (no need to restart PG instance):

```
# create extension hstore;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

And do a quick check:

```
# select hstore(ROW(1,2));
        hstore        
----------------------
 "f1"=>"1", "f2"=>"2"
(1 row)
```

Comment: So do I need to do `cd src/postgresql-12.2/contrib/hstore` before `./configure`?

Comment: No I don't think it is needed. Once you have run `./configure` for all PG source code, these settings will be reused when compiling an extension in the same source code tree.

Comment: Then, I was unable to understand your answer. Do I need to `make` and `make install` from `postgres/contrib/hstore` again just after compiling postgres with my given codes in question?

Comment: Yes this is what I just did with PG 12.2. source code and then I have run without error  `create extension hstore;`.